# Django 2: TemplateDoesNotExist even if files placed properly

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have encountered interesting problem on Django 2.

In my `settings.py` I have written this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

After that I have created folder `templates` in my projects root folder.

Then I have created app with name `front` and added it into my `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`:

[image: app_image]

Inside my `views.py` I have added this view:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'front/index')
```

I have assigned its url like this:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

When I'm trying to access to this view I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
front/index
```

Why this happening? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'front/index')
```

to

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'front/index.html')
```